# Asp.NET Core + OIDC Code Flow Exception: Correlation failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid-connect

I am running into an issue with single sign on on ASP.NET Core web site, using currently recommended `code` flow.

The top level error message is:

```
Exception: Correlation failed.
            Unknown location
```

Coming from: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler<TOptions>.HandleRequestAsync()`

With a **raw exception**:

```
System.Exception: Correlation failed.
```

Website ends up in an endless redirect loop between:

1. website: `signin-oidc?code=...`
2. website: `destination page (needs **Authorisation**!)`
3. SSO: `authorize?client_id=...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further investigation revealed that Chrome **browser blocks** local website **authentication cookie** during redirect between:

1. `signin-oidc?code=...` endpoint
2. destination page (which requires **Authorisation!**)

With the stated reason:

> The cookie was blocked because it had the `SameSite=Strict` attribute and the request was made from a different site. This includes top-level navigation requests initiated by other sites.

It turned out that, because `signin-oidc` endpoint is triggered as a 302 redirect from SSO server, then `signin-oidc` endpoint issues another 302 redirect, double redirect is threated as being initiated from "other site".

The **destination page** which originally triggered SSO redirect requires **[Authorization]** and authentication cookie being present. Because the cookie is blocked by destination page issues another login redirect to SSO and starts redirect loop.

```cs
services.AddCookie("cookie", options =>
{
    //...
    
    // `SameSite=Strict` only works for SPA apps where
    // initial "catch-all" `index.html` page is not secured.
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
})
```